# How to set Jlabel auto vertical top and bottom position

Tags: java, swing

Hi i trying to put two JLabels into one Jlabel something like that:

[image]

the problem is that. I cant position a first JLabel on the top of parent JLabel and second JLabel on the bottom of parent JLabel. Also i would use HorizontalCenter.

i trying to use the following code but is doesnt work. first Jlabel is placed on the same spot like second Jlabel

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    JLabel background = new JLabel(icon);
    background.setSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

    JLabel textUpper = new JLabel("UPPPER",JLabel.CENTER);
    textUpper.setSize(image.getWidth(), 30);
    textUpper.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    textUpper.setForeground(Color.red);

    JLabel textLower = new JLabel("LOWER",JLabel.CENTER);
    textLower.setSize(image.getWidth(), 30);
    textLower.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    textLower.setForeground(Color.red);


    background.add(textUpper);
    background.add(textLower,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    background.printAll(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();

    return img;
```

Can anybody help? I Will greatful for help

Comment: Have you tried to change the `LayoutManager` of your main `JLabel`?

Comment: Add the line `background.setLayout(new BorderLayout())` for example.

Comment: *"trying to put two JLabels into one Jlabel"* Why not try to put two labels into one **`JPanel`?**  (Tip: It will be easier).